# finish() on an Activity closes app then briefly shows previous Application

Tags: android, android-activity, activity-finish

In my App, Activity1 launches Activity2 with "startActivityForResult()".

When Activity2 is done, the following code is called:

*Activity2.java*

```
private void finishActivity(final boolean accepted)
{
  Intent returnIntent = new Intent();

  setResult(accepted ? RESULT_OK : RESULT_CANCELED, returnIntent);

  finish();
}
```

Activity1 receives this callback, and if the result is not RESULT_OK, it also finishes.

*Activity1.java*

```
@Override

protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
{
  super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

  if (requestCode == Globals.REQUEST_CODE_TOS)
  {
    if (resultCode != RESULT_OK)
      finish();
  }
}
```

After Activity1 finishes the app closes, as expected.

THE PROBLEM --

However, after my app closes, instead of going to the home screen, a previous application on the stack **briefly launches forward**, then closes also!  Then I get to the home screen.

In the Android bug tracker, I see a similar bug listed for the case when the back button is pressed, which I believe is the same as calling finish():

https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=71067

I'm seeing this on a Nexus 5, running 4.4.4.

Is this just a bug?  Or are there any workarounds for the behavior?

EDIT --

To clarify the behavior I desire:

In Google Maps, if you decline the TOS popup, the app closes and you go directly to the home screen.  There is no awkward flash to some previously opened app.

Comment: Probably a system bug...

Comment: "a previous application on the stack briefly launches forward, then closes also!" Whats is 'previous application'? Do you mean Activity2?

Comment: @MarcinS. No, I mean a previous application -- for example, after calling finish() on my top activity, the Play Store briefly pops up and then pops back, finally bringing me to the home screen.

Comment: @DeeV But, that's not the behavior I see in other apps, for example Google Maps, when you decline the TOS agreement, the app just closes and goes to the homescreen.  That's the behavior I want, without the awkward flash to some previous application..

Comment: I think I misunderstood the problem.  It would happen if you opened the app from the Google Play Store.  If you opened the app from the launcher, then you should go to the launcher.  This sounds like it may actually be a system bug if it's bringing up a previous App back in to View when it should have been long gone.

Answer (score 2):

This is decidedly the same issue as the [one you linked in your question](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=71067) (I've been following it for months, as I own a Nexus 5 myself). It was actually [fixed in the AOSP](https://android-review.googlesource.com/#/c/98918), but that particular fix doesn't seem to have found its way into the N5 yet. I've got my fingers crossed for a fix in Lollipop, but we'll see when that rolls out.

As for a workaround, I don't think any exists at the moment, although if I'm wrong on that I would love to know - I work on an app myself which does something similar (manually calls `finish()` the bottom-most activity in the stack when closed via the back button).

Comment: Yes, I'm seeing the same exact behavior -- yet Google Maps seems to avoid this pitfall.  You can test by clearing Data on Google Maps and then launching -- then decline the TOS.  Maps closes cleanly and just goes to the homescreen.

Comment: So it does. I'm wondering if maybe they simulate a home button press rather than calling `finish()`. I saw a glimpse of the regular map activity underneath the TOS one, so it's possible they did that in order to circumvent having to finish all the activities in the stack.

Answer (score 0):

Might be the empty Intent you return via `setResult()`. Have you tried `null` here, instead?

Comment: I just tried it -- null does the same, but thank you for the idea.  It seems to be a bug...